# Enable service broker

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to enable service broker coz without enabling it alerts and database mail won't work.the database I'm using has mirroring and replication,I tried the option with rollback but didn't work

statement used:`Alter database test set enable_broker with rollback immediate`

results:

> alter database statement failed)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Database Main requires service broker enabled for `msdb` - which is enabled by default unless someone disables it.

Refer [BOL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191442(v=sql.105).aspx) :

> Enabling Service Broker in any database requires a database lock. If Service Broker was deactivated in msdb, to enable Database Mail, first stop SQL Server Agent so Service Broker can obtain the necessary lock.

Check using below T-SQL

```
select is_broker_enabled, name 
from sys.databases
where state_desc = 'ONLINE'
order by database_id
```